# Maven: running task only on specific git branch

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am wondering if it is possible to make maven git branch aware?

i.e:

```
// if branch == master
<dryRun>true</dryRun>

// else
<dryRun>false</dryRun>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [select maven profile based on git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220517/select-maven-profile-based-on-git-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, maven doesn't know where it is running.
its just a simple file system that has the files and someone ran the maven command with some pom.xml
however you could use env vars to set a profile for the run. i think thats one of the maven ways of doing things differently based on the env you are running on.